# What is the purpose of the default value in props in vue if vue still throws an error?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, default, vue-props

I'm trying to understand whether prop validation is for the developer or the user. I intentionally left a component empty

I did not pass a value (by the way, what is this passed value called?): `<card />` 
The correct way: `<card :name="name" />`

```
props:{
    name: { default: "John Doe" }
```

However, when I leave the component empty, without passing a value, Vue uses the default value to populate the value in the template section while leaving an error in the console:
`Property or method "name" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.`

What if I want to have a default? I will continue to get that error.

Comment: Please share its parent code from where you are passing name to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prop validation is useful for both developers and users, but optional.

I think the issue lies with this line (I refactored the input to 'myName' to explain):
`<card :name="myName" />`

The error is coming through because `myName` is not defined properly before it is passed to the component.

These will work as static examples:

- `<card name="Jesse" />` Because name is not bound with `:` or `v-bind:`
- `<card :name="'Jesse'" />` Because name is bound here, but to a literal string 'Jesse'

`<card :name="myName" />`  will work, you just need to assert that myName is not undefined.

`myName` itself can be a prop in the parent component too if you like, Eg:
 `props: { myName: { default: "Jesse"} }`